# Polylang issue after install

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I've installed Polylang to a new WordPress website. I've added the default language but then every page is white. What can I do to solve that?

The permalinks is: `postname`.

I've tried to change the settings of the plugin or something else but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperantly, this can happen when the theme cannot differentiate between Polylang and WPML and then tries to make use of WPML specific functions.

More information about this can be found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/polyang-white-screen-after-installing/).

And the solution is to add the following line inside *wp-config.php*:

```
define('PLL_WPML_COMPAT', false);
```